# Reading scientific numbers in xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

Pretty simple question but haven't been able to find a good answer.

In Excel, I am generating files that need to be automatically read. They are read by an ID number, but the format I get is setting it as text. When using xlrd, I get this format:

> 5.5112E+12

When I need it in this format:

> 5511195414392

What is the best way to achieve this? I would like to avoid using xlwt but if it is necessary I could use help on getting started in that process too

Comment: (1) You need to explain in more detail what you are trying to do. In Excel, you are generating files how? Manually? "The format I get is setting it as text": get how? setting what? (2) Excel saves all numbers as 64-bit floats. It is up to you how you display what xlrd retrieves from the file. In the case of an ID number, `str(int(x))` would be much better.

Answer (score 4):

Give this a shot:

```
import decimal

decimalNotation = decimal.Decimal(scientificNotationValueFromExcel)
```

I made the following quick program to test it out. The Excel file it is reading from has a single entry in the first cell.

```
from xlrd import *
import decimal

workbook = open_workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

value = sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

print decimal.Decimal(value)
```

Comment: (1) `from xlrd import *` is not recommended. (2) Using `decimal` is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I used the CSV module to figure this out, as it read the cells correctly.